# Asynchronous Request to Facebook API with Redux

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, asynchronous, callback, redux

I am using Redux and trying to make a call to Facebook API with their JS SDK. I've only ever used promises with Redux and so since the method FB.getLoginStatus just returns a simple JS object, I'm not sure how to ensure that the payload doesn't return undefined.

With redux-promise, you add it to the applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise)... and then it ensures nothing is returned until the promise resolves. But I don't know how to do that here.

I've also used async/await functions with React Native without an issue, but I tried using them here and for some reason the code still returns the payload, before the asynchronous request (await ...) is finished. So I tried working with redux-await, but couldn't get it to work.

```
export function getLoginStatus() {
  var res = FB.getLoginStatus(function(res) {
    console.log(res);
  });

  console.log("res ", res);

  return {
    type: GET_LOGIN_STATUS,
    payload: res
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, things can get a little tricky as I've not used `redux-promise`. And I can't tell exactly what else you have tried. But this would be my first shot:

```
async function _getLoginStatus() {
  var payload = new Promise( (resolve, fail) => {
    FB.getLoginStatus((res)=>resolve(res));
  });
  return {
    type: GET_LOGIN_STATUS,
    payload: payload
  }
}

// Last time I exported an async function I needed this HYMMV
export let getLoginStatus = _getLoginStatus;
```

And then elsewhere in the code:

```
import {getLoginStatus} from 'whatever.js';

var payloadResult = await getLoginStatus();
```